# Extracting value from a key value pair in a .txt file using python

Tags: python, python-import, key-value

I have a text file containing a single line containing a key and a value.
Eg: 
Name: xyz

From python how can I import that text file and fetch the name ie., xyz

Comment: how are they separated, the key and value?

Comment: One key-value per line?

Comment: `key,value = open('filename.txt').read().strip().split(':')`

Comment: what i mean is... what is the delimiter between key and value? Is it a colon like the user above assumed, or is it something else?

Comment: @omu_negru It sais that in the question; `Name: xyz`

Comment: @Cleared it first says `key and a value. Eg: Name: xyz` . Then he mentions fetching the name , which he binds to xyz. This is where my confusion is coming from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
open('filename.txt').readline().split(':')[1].strip()
```

- `open('filename.txt')` opens the file
- `.read` reads the line
- `.split(':')[1]` splits the line on `:` and takes the second element (the value)
- `.strip()` strips the value from the first space

Comment: you can simply just call `strip` once; either at the end or in the middle but with `split(': ')`. Also, to avoid errors substituting `read()` with `readline()` might also be a good idea

Comment: What if the text contains `Key:Value`  (no space) or `Key:  Value` (two spaces)? Then my solution feels more robust. But i agree with using `readline()` instead of `read()`

Comment: Remove the middle `strip()` and try the cases with no or double spaces.

Comment: Yeah, the middle `strip()` is unneccesary :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case, if you need to store more values there i think the cleanest solution would be to use the config module from python. There you do not need to parse anything on your own:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Other then that you could read out the file like suggested in a comment already

This could look like this:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

cf_parser = SafeConfigParser()
cf_parser.read("file")
name = cf_parser.get("section", "name")
```

The file then could look like:

```
[section]
name = xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is named keyfile.txt, this work:

```
f = open('keyfile.txt')
s = f.readline()
s.split()[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. It uses list comprehensions and worked with a file like yours on my local machine using Python 2.7

```
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as file:
    rows = ( line.split(':') for line in file)
    dict = { row[0]:row[1] for row in rows }
for item in dict:
    print dict[item]
```